# Simulate two root windows on single monitor with use of RANDR extension

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr, xephyr

This question might seen similar to [Emulating extra displays](https://superuser.com/questions/538789) but it's different in the important detail.

Suppose I'd like to test a feature for certain window manager with multi monitor support using RANDR extension. Seems like it is impossible to achieve this using `Xrandr`/`Xdmx`. I've tried different combinations with `+extension RANDR` and `+xinerama` parameters both to `Xrandr` and `Xdmx` but without luck so far. Also, I didn't find any clue in man pages for both commands.

My simple case is:

`Xephyr -screen 800x800+0+0 -ac :1 &
sleep 1
Xephyr -screen 800x800+800+0 -ac :2 &
sleep 1
Xdmx +extension RANDR -xinput local -display :1 -display :2 -ac :3 &
sleep 1
DISPLAY=:3 window-manager`

I've also tried to simply use only `Xephyr`:

`Xephyr +extension RANDR -screen 800x800+0+0 -screen 800x800+800+0 -ac :3 &
sleep 1
DISPLAY=:3 window-manager`

but obviously it creates two separate X screens, so the root window is not shared between the screens.

Is there any other way for getting `xrandr` to report two available outputs with my case?

Comment: You have tried `+xinerama` and `+extension RANDR` together? Obviously you need both. If that doesn't work, I'd look at the source and figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried all of the combination. It is always possibility, that common root window for separate screens simply doesn't work or is not possible with `Xrandr`/`Xdmx` for providing more than one RANDR output.